# How do i identify the page navigation button in footer of HTML page to click it in Selenium?

Tags: dom, selenium, xpath

I need to identify the page navigation button at the footer of the form and click the >>> (last page) button if it is active, else not click it at all.

```
<table id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:j_id256_table" class="rich-dtascroller-table " cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="text-align:right">

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="rich-datascr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button">

            ««

        </td>
        <td class="rich-datascr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button"></td>
        <td class="rich-datascr-act ">

            1

        </td>
        <td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '2'});"></td>
        <td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '3'});"></td>
        <td class=" rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'next'});"></td>
        <td class=" rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'last'});"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the above scenario the first page <<< is disabled and the last button is enabled. So i need to use DOM or XPath to do in Selenium these 2:-

1) Check if >>> is enabled
2) Click on that button.

So what is the DOM or XPath to get hold of the appropriate element to click ?

Comment: You can use xpath to get the class of the td in the table. I think in the class rich-datascr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button the dsbld specifies the button is disabled. You can use String class contains method to find out if text is present in the class. If it is present then button is disabled. Else it is enabled. This is just a hunch. Let me know if this works.

Comment: You need code for Selenium IDE or java/python/etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the ">>>" on your DOM elements. I'm going to assume that it's under  element too

```
element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath, "//td[contains(.,'>>>')]")
if (!element.getAttribute("class").contains("rich-datascr-button-dsbld"))  // should not have
{
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer if you think this solve your issue. ;)